# How to connect using python-tds driver to sql server which is forcing encryption?

Tags: python, sql-server, ssl, encryption, certificate

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2016 with python-tds driver using NTLM authentication. The sql server is forcing encryption (SQL Configuration manager) as per this screenshot. There is no certificate attached to it on the next tab.

[image]

The server is on AWS EC2 machine but I don't think this bring any difference? This code (which is confirmed to work for a different server with no encryption):

```
import pytds
from pytds.login import NtlmAuth

ntlm = NtlmAuth(user_name='domain\username', password='password')
pytds_conn = pytds.connect(dsn='11.22.33.44', database='master',
                           port=1433, auth=ntlm, autocommit=True)
```

gives this error:

*pytds.tds_base.Error: Client does not have encryption enabled but it is required by server, enable encryption and try connecting again*

I then tried to use `cafile` parameter within `pytds.connect` function. So I created .cer file and corresponding .pem file following this link : http://www.richardnichols.net/2014/03/creating-and-importing-an-external-certificate-to-sql-server/

After uploading the .cer certificate using the query:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE testCer   
    FROM FILE = 'c:\Temp\test.cer'
```

and adding parameter `cafile=test.pem` to pytds.connect I got this error:

*OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]*

Do you know how (or whether at all) can I make the python-tds NTLM connection working when the encryption is forced and there is no certificate attached to it in SQL Server Network Configuration?